# How to check if letter is upper or lower in PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8

I have texts in UTF-8 with diacritic characters also, and would like to check if first letter of this text is upper case or lower case. How to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to check if a letter is upper or lower?

Comment: @Elizabeth Buckwalter Because I work out other text from this text, and If this first letter is upper than I must do the same with second one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is my opinion that making a `preg_` call is the most direct, concise, and reliable call versus the other posted solutions here.

```
echo preg_match('~^\p{Lu}~u', $string) ? 'upper' : 'lower';
```

My pattern breakdown:

```
~      # starting pattern delimiter 
^      #match from the start of the input string
\p{Lu} #match exactly one uppercase letter (unicode safe)
~      #ending pattern delimiter 
u      #enable unicode matching
```

Please take notice when `ctype_` and `< 'a'` fail with this battery of tests.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4eGBV))

```
$tests = ['âa', 'Bbbbb', 'Éé', 'iou', 'Δδ'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "\n{$test}:";
    echo "\n\tPREG:  " , preg_match('~^\p{Lu}~u', $test)      ? 'upper' : 'lower';
    echo "\n\tCTYPE: " , ctype_upper(mb_substr($test, 0, 1))  ? 'upper' : 'lower';
    echo "\n\t< a:   " , mb_substr($test, 0, 1) < 'a'         ? 'upper' : 'lower';

    $chr = mb_substr ($test, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
    echo "\n\tMB:    " , mb_strtoupper($chr, "UTF-8") == $chr ? 'upper' : 'lower';
}
```

Output:

```
âa:
    PREG:  lower
    CTYPE: lower
    < a:   lower
    MB:    lower
Bbbbb:
    PREG:  upper
    CTYPE: upper
    < a:   upper
    MB:    upper
Éé:               <-- trouble
    PREG:  upper
    CTYPE: lower  <-- uh oh
    < a:   lower  <-- uh oh
    MB:    upper
iou:
    PREG:  lower
    CTYPE: lower
    < a:   lower
    MB:    lower
Δδ:               <-- extended beyond question scope
    PREG:  upper  <-- still holding up
    CTYPE: lower
    < a:   lower
    MB:    upper  <-- still holding up
```

If anyone needs to differentiate between uppercase letters, lowercase letters, and non-letters see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992383/2943403).

---

It may be extending the scope of this question too far, but if your input characters are especially squirrelly (they might not exist in a category that `Lu` can handle), you may want to check if the first character has case variants:

> \p{L&} or \p{Cased_Letter}: a letter that exists in lowercase and uppercase variants (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt).

- Source: https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

To include Roman Numerals ("Number Letters") with `SMALL` variants, you can add that extra range to the pattern if necessary.

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5kao7))

```
echo preg_match('~^[\p{Lu}\x{2160}-\x{216F}]~u', $test) ? 'upper' : 'not upper';
```

---

Premature-Update: After `mb_ucfirst()` and `mb_lcfirst()` are brought into the language, then there might be a reliable non-regex approach.

```
echo mb_ucfirst($test) === $test ? 'upper (or first character is not a letter)' : 'lower';
```

Or

```
echo mb_lcfirst($test) !== $test ? 'upper' : 'lower (or first character is not a letter)';
```

[PHP RFC: Multibyte for ucfirst, lcfirst functions, mb_ucfirst mb_lcfirst](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mb_ucfirst)

I'll need to check if there are locale specific caveats like with Vietnamese.

Comment: Special thanks to [@Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribiżew) for helping me to find these characters at fileformat.info.

Answer (score 53):

```
function starts_with_upper($str) {
    $chr = mb_substr ($str, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
    return mb_strtolower($chr, "UTF-8") != $chr;
}
```

Note that mb_substr is necessary to correctly isolate the first character.

[**Working Demo Online**](https://3v4l.org/96LHf)

Comment: Doesn't always work.  There are Unicode characters that are capital letters (i.e., category Lu) but don't have a lowercase mapping.  Mostly, the mathematical bold/italic/double-struck letters.

Comment: @dan04 That's an excellent point. On top of that, there's title case (LT). However, the mbstring extension does not expose functions to userspace to test for those properties. It's a pity because the functionality is there -- see http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/mbstring/php_unicode.h?revision=296679&view=markup

Comment: @dan04 How this function will handle this situation?

Comment: To clarify, "There are over 100 lowercase letters in the Unicode Standard that have no direct uppercase equivalent." -- http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html

Answer (score 29):

Use `ctype_upper` for check upper case:

```
$a = array("Word", "word", "wOrd");

foreach($a as $w)
{
    if(ctype_upper($w{0}))
    {
        print $w;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with non-latin characters, such as the nordic ÆØÅ.

Comment: Those are [latin chars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). `ctype_upper` doesn't work with *non-ASCII* chars (including those nordic latins, as well as many other latin, and especially non-latin chars).

Comment: Thank you for both comments! But in the question stands "UTF-8 with diacritic characters" and it works fine. If you need a function for other chars, use answer from Artefacto.

Comment: This answer is incorrect for two reasons because you failed to test multibyte characters as the question clearly states.  1.  You cannot grab a multibyte character by the `0` byte offset -- you will only access the first byte of the letter.  2. `ctype_` doesn't provide the necessary multibyte support for this task.

Answer (score 11):

Tried ?

```
$str = 'the text to test';
if($str{0} === strtoupper($str{0})) {
   echo 'yepp, its uppercase';
}
else{
   echo 'nope, its not upper case';
}
```

Comment: $str{0} is the same as $str[0]. Sometimes substr(string, start, length) is useful with start or length being negative.

Comment: This answer is incorrect for two reasons because you failed to test multibyte characters as the question clearly states.  1.  You cannot grab a multibyte character by the `0` byte offset -- you will only access the first byte of the letter.  2. `strtoupper` doesn't provide the necessary multibyte support for this task.

Answer (score 5):

Note that PHP provides the `ctype` family like [ctype_upper](http://php.net/ctype_upper).

You have to set the locale correctly via [setLocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) first to get it to work with UTF-8.
See the comment on [ctype_alpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) for instance.

Usage:

```
if ( ctype_upper( $str[0] )) {
    // deal with 1st char of $str is uppercase
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on UTF-8. That comment on php.net has -2 (down) votes.
Try:
`setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf-8');
return ctype_upper('П') === false;`

Comment: Getting the `setLocale()` setting to be correct in a dynamic envoronment can be a hassle.  More importantly you cannot access a whole multibyte character by the first byte offset.  This answer is incorrect/unstable.  https://3v4l.org/38R6f

Answer (score 5):

I didn't want numbers and others to be an upper char, so I use:

```
if(preg_match('/[A-Z]$/',$char)==true)
{
   // this must be an upper char
   echo $char
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect because: 1. It is not checking the first character, it is checking the last character.  2. It is not attempting to match multibyte characters as the question clearly states.

Answer (score 5):

As used in Kohana 2 autoloader function:

```
echo $char < 'a' ? 'uppercase' : 'lowercase';
```

When a string character is cast to integer it evaluates to its ASCII number. As you know in the ASCII table first there are some control characters and others. Then the uppercase letters from the Latin alphabet. And then the lowercase letters from the Latin alphabet. Thus you can easily check whether the code of a letter is smaller or bigger than the small latin character `a`.

BTW this is around twice as fast than a solution with regular expressions.

Comment: this is the fastest even in utf

Comment: This answer is incorrect because you failed to test multibyte characters as the question clearly states.

Answer (score 2):

What about just:

```
if (ucfirst($string) == $string) {dosomething();}
```

Comment: No. This is inappropriate/incorrect for the question asked.  https://3v4l.org/1GpYX

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in a nice function, I've used this:

```
function _is_upper ($in_string)
{
    return($in_string === strtoupper($in_string) ? true : false);
}
```

Then just call..

```
if (_is_upper($mystring))
{
  // Do....
}
```

Comment: Your solution is inappropriate/incorrect for the question asked.  Your solution does not provide support for "diacritic characters" as clearly stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution in PHP 7 is using [IntlChar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intlchar.php#intlchar.constants.char-direction-first-strong-isolate)

> **IntlChar** provides access to a number of utility methods that can be used to access information about Unicode characters.

```
$tests = ['âa', 'Bbbbb', 'Éé', 'iou', 'Δδ'];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "{$test}:\t";
    echo IntlChar::isUUppercase(mb_substr($test, 0, 1)) ? 'upper' : 'lower';
    echo PHP_EOL; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
âa:     lower
Bbbbb:  upper
Éé:     upper
iou:    lower
Δδ:     upper
```

While @mickmackusa's first pattern (`~^\p{Lu}~u`) is good, it will give the wrong result for different general category values (other than "Lu" uppercase letter category).  **Note, he has since extended the pattern at the bottom of his answer to include Roman Numerals.*

**For example**

- Ⅷ => ⅷ
- Ⅼ => ⅼ
- Ⅿ => ⅿ
- Ⅾ => ⅾ
- Ⅽ => ⅽ

---

```
 var_dump(preg_match('~^\p{Lu}~u', 'Ⅷ') ? 'upper' : 'lower'); // Resutl: lower
 var_dump(preg_match('~^\p{Lu}~u', 'ⅷ') ? 'upper' : 'lower'); // Result: lower
```

**But**

```
var_dump(IntlChar::isUUppercase(mb_substr('Ⅷ', 0, 1)) ? 'upper' : 'lower'); // Result: upper    
var_dump(IntlChar::isUUppercase(mb_substr('ⅷ', 0, 1)) ? 'upper' : 'lower'); // Result: lower
```

Make sure to use [IntlChar::isUUppercase](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.isuuppercase.php) but not [IntlChar::isupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.isupper.php) if you want to check for characters that are also uppercase but have a different general category value

**Note:** This library depends on [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) (Internationalization extension)

Comment: @mickmackusa True, I like your approach and i think it's slightly faster. But I wouldn't use regex for such a simple task.

Comment: You'd rather use a `mb_` function then a library-dependent class method? Okay, your choice. I always favor regex when it provides the most direct approach AND sensible performance isn't lost.  It is good to provide choices to researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes if that increases my code readability. Again your solution is great but without your pattern breakdown it may take a little more time for someone stupid like me to get it.

Comment: I'll investigate your comparison after work.  Thanks for pinging me.  Are you saying that my answer fails on Roman Numerals?

Comment: @mickmackusa  Yes, some of the Roman Numerals and also some of the (So) category have case variants. And i think it would be useful to take care of those cases too.

Comment: Definitely upvote-worthy.  Thanks for sharing the difference.  (I never found time to investigate a pattern change that would cover those fringe cases.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ctype_upper(&value)){
    echo 'uppercase';
}
else {
    echo 'not upper case';
}
```

Comment: `ctype_` doesn't provide the necessary multibyte support for this task.  The OP is very clear about needing to process "diacritic characters".  This code-only answer is incorrect/inappropriate.