# PHP function to check if a string is all lowercase

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a function that returns TRUE if a string is all lowercase without using any built-in PHP functions. How can I do that?

This is what I was working with, but using [ctype_lower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php).

```
$string = "string";

if (ctype_lower($string)) {
    echo $string . ' is all lowercase letters.';
} else {
    echo $string . ' is not all lowercase letters.';
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use built-in PHP functions? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php

Comment: without using any built-in functions? out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Do you need to handle ASCII only, or do you need to cover more (latin1, UNICODE, etc.)?  If you need to cover full UNICODE, then this is quite difficult.

Comment: I'm new to PHP and i'm trying to practice as much as possible, would be possible to do that or it can be achieved only using built-in functions ?

Comment: @Notsrik that makes sense. Make sure you read this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels/

Comment: Please post the code you've come up so far. You shouldn't ask people for a solution, instead you need to show your research.

Comment: @Notsrik You don't practice by asking others and not trying anything.

Comment: thank you, just my question with code that was using but with ctype_lower

Comment: Are you truly looking for a solution that doesn't use *any built-in PHP functions at all*, or did you simply mean that you don't want to use any functions such as `ctype_lower` which do all the work for you?

Answer (score 11):

Well, if you just want a simple-purpose check, you could just compare the original string with an `strtolower`red string. Of course, it won't be foolproof. Like this:

```
function check_lowercase_string($string) {
    return ($string === strtolower($string));
}

$string = 'Hi! I am a string';
var_dump(check_lowercase_string($string)); // false
var_dump(check_lowercase_string('test')); // true
```

A *painful* attempt of no functions:

```
function check_lowercase_string($string) {
    $chars = '';
    // map all small characters
    for($alpha = 'a'; $alpha != 'aa'; $alpha++) { $small[] = $alpha; }
    $l = 0; // not strlen() :p
    while (@$string[$l] != '') {
        $l++;
    }
    for($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) { // for each string input piece
        foreach($small as $letter) { // for each mapped letter
            if($string[$i] == $letter) {
                $chars .= $letter; // simple filter
            }
        }
    }

    // if they are still equal in the end then true, if they are not, false
    return ($chars === $string);
}

var_dump(check_lowercase_string('teSt')); // false
```

Comment: Agree, no need of ternary operator at all. Just return the expression which will return boolean.

Comment: thanks it results to boolean anyway

Comment: Doesn't `strtolower` count as a builtin PHP function?

Comment: @faintsignal well which solution you want to propose? map out all the small characters and loop them and compare them each? a helpful advice would be appriciated

Comment: Hey, I'm just pointing out what the OP asked for.

Comment: @faintsignal well i thought about it but it would be just weird having to loop all small caps and having them compare each piece, anyway maybe this question is best suited on codegolf

Comment: @Ghost Agreed. I'm curious if (s)he overstated the requirement. Though you have to admit it becomes a more interesting, albeit unpractical, problem to solve if one literally cannot use any built-in functions.

Comment: `for($alpha = 'a'; $alpha != 'aa'; $alpha++) { $small[] = $alpha; }` What is this?

Comment: @Rolice same concept as `range('a', 'z')`;, well cant use functions

Comment: @Ghost, nice, I wasn't aware that PHP can do character incremental, like in other languages. However, I think it will be easier to operate with numeric representation, since ASCII representation of lowercase is between 97 and 122 and uppercase is in the range of 65 - 90.

Comment: @Ghost Props for jumping through that flaming hoop, nicely done. Emphatic upvote.

Comment: @Rolice yeah it was weird when i saw it the first time either, yes strings can be incremented

Comment: @Emissary man that was simpler haha! nice answer, you should post that too and mostly the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [ctype_lower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-lower.php), which is inbuilt, so you don't want that :c.

But you can use the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814880/how-to-check-if-letter-is-upper-or-lower-in-php). And put together a loop which checks for the first character. If uppercase then return true, and if not, then remove the first character of string and continue like that through the entire string.