# Sort By Alphabet then Numbers Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections, laravel-collection

I am looking for a way to sort the collection in such a way that name values starting with the alphabet comes at the top and then name values that start with numbers. For example:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'b', 'symbol' => '#'],
    ['name' => '2a', 'symbol' => '$'],
    ['name' => '1', 'symbol' => '@'],
    ['name' => 'a', 'symbol' => '%']
]);
```

The above collection should be sorted like this:

```
[
    [
        "name" => "a",
        "symbol" => "%",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "b",
        "symbol" => "#",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "1",
        "symbol" => "@",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "2a",
        "symbol" => "$",
    ],
]
```

But this is what I get when I sort it using `sortBy` method:

```
$collection->sortBy('name')->values()->all();
[
    [
        "name" => "1",
        "symbol" => "@",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "2a",
        "symbol" => "$",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "a",
        "symbol" => "%",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "b",
        "symbol" => "#",
    ],
]
```

Any idea how to sort this collection so that names starting with letters come first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own custom comparator function to sort these collection objects using [`sort`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sort).

Compare both names by checking they are all alphabets. If both are alphabets, then usual string comparison using [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) shall suffice. If either of them is an alphabet, push them to higher ranks by returning value `-1`, meaning to be placed above in the sorted order. If both are numerical or alphanumeric,  use [`strcasecmp`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) again.

```
<?php

$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'b', 'symbol' => '#'],
    ['name' => '2a', 'symbol' => '$'],
    ['name' => '1', 'symbol' => '@'],
    ['name' => 'a', 'symbol' => '%']
]);

$collection = $collection->sort(function($a,$b){
    $a_is_alphabet = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $a['name']) === 1;
    $b_is_alphabet = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+$/', $b['name']) === 1;

    if($a_is_alphabet && $b_is_alphabet){
        return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
    }elseif($a_is_alphabet){
        return -1;
    }elseif($b_is_alphabet){
        return 1;
    }

    return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want purely alphabetical name values to have top priority, then I assume natural sorting so that, say `a2` comes before `a10`. Just write two rules in a custom callback in a `sort()` method call.

False evaluations are ordered before true evaluations when sorting ASC, so merely write the `$b` element before the `$a` element to sort DESC.  To break any ties on the first comparison, call `strnatcmp()`.

[Laravel adopted arrow function syntax back in 2019.](https://laravel-news.com/short-arrow-functions)

Code: ([Basic PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/BsflO))

```
$collection->sort(fn($a, $b) =>
    (ctype_alpha($b['name']) <=> ctype_alpha($a['name']))
    ?: strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name'])
);
```

If you, more specifically only want to check if the first character is a letter, you can use `$a['name'][0]` and `$b['name'][0]`.  If the strings might have a multi-byte first character then [a regex approach might be best](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55992883/2943403).