# Last character of php string in php

Tags: php

In C the last character of a string is always '\0' Is it same for PHP as well? If not, then what's the last character of a string in PHP?

Comment: Nothing. PHP doesn't need a terminating character for strings. It handles these things internally.

Comment: then if i want to run a loop from the first charecter to the last of the string how can i do that in php??

Comment: What do you need the /0 for? If you just want to check length or manipulate the string in some way, there is a multitude of functions for that, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: `for ($i=1; $i<strlen($mystring); $i++) echo $mystring[$i];`

Comment: This could answer your question in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601032/php-iterate-on-string-characters

Comment: i have a csv file containing some data for database.now i have to convert each line of data in sql format. the data in csv file is as follows:"abc,abc,1243,abc" I have to make them like thi s" 'abc','abc',123,'abc'  ".

Comment: Use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for parsing csv files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for( $i = 0, $len = strlen( $string ); $i < $len; $i++ )
{
    $char = $string[ $i ];
    // do something with $char
}
```

... is one way to do it.

Another way, is simply using PHP function [`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) (which creates an array of the individual characters of the string (unless you pass it the second argument `$split_length` of a different length than the default)):

```
foreach( str_split( $string ) as $char )
{
    // do something with $char
}
```

... etc.

Edit:

As an addendum to your comments to your question; use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for parsing csv files.

Comment: this foreach comment is usefull too

Answer (score 3):

Strings in PHP are binary safe, which means that they can contain `\0` as well. Therefore, there's no termination character that could be used.

Instead, the length of the string is stored separately inside PHP's [internal variable representation](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/php/ch14_06.htm). This also makes string length calculations much faster.

> i have a csv file containing some data for database.now i have to convert each line of data in sql format. the data in csv file is as follows:"abc,abc,1243,abc" I have to make them like thi s" 'abc','abc',123,'abc' ".

First of all, you should use `fgetcsv()` for that; it turns the whole line (or lines in some cases) into one array.

I'm going to guess you want to store those values into a database; you could use this:

```
if ($arr = fgetcsv($f)) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute($arr);
}
```

This assumes each line in your CSV has four items; to make it more generic you could use the length of `$arr` to construct the number of place holders to add in the query.

Comment: @AngshuGuha If it solved your problem, then why accept the other answer? ;-)

Comment: @AngshuGuha Normally that's what you would use upvote for; the answer that solves the problem is typically the one that gets accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To loop over the characters in a string, you write:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen($string); i++) {
    $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
    // Do stuff with $char
}
```

Comment: You can access characters of strings using square brackets too  `$string[$i]`

Comment: In fact, string dereferencing is much faster too.

Answer (score 1):

**I think its should be worked**

```
  $lastChar = substr($string, -1);
```

Comment: The question is more about a string terminating character, not so much about finding the actually last character. Even if it was, I'd not reverse (copy) the string, when a simple string length function would do.