# PHP: How to get characters of string one by one

Tags: php, string

```
$str = "8560841836";
$mystr = array($str);
$string = strlen($str);
for($i=0; $i<=$string; $i++){   echo $string[$i]."\n";  }
```

This code print this string in one line but I want it to be print in one char in line and other so on...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - iterate on string characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601032/php-iterate-on-string-characters)

Answer (score 12):

From [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

> Characters within strings may be accessed and modified by specifying the *zero-based offset* of the desired character after the string using square array brackets, as in `$str[42]`. Think of a string as an *array of characters* for this purpose. The functions substr() and substr_replace() can be used when you want to extract or replace more than 1 character.
>
> **Note:** Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in `$str{42}`, for the same purpose.
>
> **Warning**
>   Internally, PHP strings are byte arrays. As a result, accessing or modifying a string using array brackets is not multi-byte safe, and should only be done with strings that are in a single-byte encoding such as ISO-8859-1.

Examples:

```
// Get the first character of a string
$str = 'This is a test.';
$first = $str[0]; // 't'

// Get the third character of a string
$third = $str[2]; // 'i'

// Get the last character of a string.
$str = 'This is still a test.';
$last = $str[strlen($str)-1];  // '.'

// Modify the last character of a string
$str = 'Look at the sea';
$str[strlen($str)-1] = 'e'; // 'Look at the see'
```

So in your case, it is very easy:

```
$str = '8560841836';
$len = strlen($str);

for($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) // < and not <=, cause the index starts at 0!
    echo $str[$i]."\n";
```

Comment: PHP has str_split () function, which is used to print every character of a string. No need to use any loop. @user3414654 answer is right.

Comment: Nice pre-php5 script though.

Comment: C habits tend to live forever!

Comment: Is there a reason $first isn't `'T'`?

Answer (score 6):

There is function `str_split('string')`. It returns:

```php
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "s"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "t"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "r"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "i"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "n"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "g"
}
```

You can pass a second parameter for maximum length of chunk.

Example: `str_split('string', 2)` returns:

```php
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "st"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "ri"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "ng"
}
```

[Documentation for `str_split` on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 2):

You confuse your string with your string length.

Moreover, you could use `$string{$i}` instead of `$string[$i]`.

And, finally, be carrefull with the end of the loop (`$i<$lenght`instead of `$i<=$lenght`)

this works :

```
<?php
$str = "8560841836";
$lenght = strlen($str);
for($i=0; $i<$lenght; $i++){   
    echo $str[$i]."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: @deceze `$str[$i]` works but if think it's recommended to use `$str{$i}`. I will look at it

Comment: No, it's neither recommended nor not recommended. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
$str = "8560841836";
$mystr = array($str);
$string = strlen($str);
for($i=0; $i<=$string; $i++){   echo $str[$i]."<br>";  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = "Split Me !";
    $start = 0;
    for ($x = $start; $x < strlen($str); $x++) {
        echo $str[$x];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `explode("", $data)` [(see this reference)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to explode the string and iterate over the result.

```
$str = "8560841836";
$mystr = explode($str);
foreach( $mystr as $string){ 
    echo $string."\n"; 
}
```