# Insert space after every non alpahumeric character

Tags: php, arrays, explode, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

Am trying to insert space before and after every non alphanumeric character in the string, for example string like (good+bad)*nice which will be entered by user, I want to make it look like ( good + bad ) * nice. The reason i want to do this, is because i want to put them in array which is going to look like this;

```
  $arr[0] = "(";
  $arr[1] = "good”;
  $arr[2] = "+”;
  $arr[3] = "bad";
  $arr[4] = ")";
  $arr[5] = "*";
  $arr[6] = "+";
```

Comment: i think if you explained the big picture a better rapport could be suggested

Comment: Are you trying to parse a mathematical expression by splitting on spaces, so that you can convert it to a stack for evaluation? Look at [ircmaxell's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php) here.... no spaces needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` to accomplish that in one line.

```
$result = preg_split('/(\w+|\W)/', '(good+bad)*nice', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

result:

```
array(
  0 => "("
  1 => "good"
  2 => "+"
  3 => "bad"
  4 => ")"
  5 => "*"
  6 => "nice"
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is what i wanted, Is there possibility of separating ) and *?

Comment: Yap, its working,, but why is it displaying odd number like [1], [3]..?

Comment: it's because `preg_split()` returns bunch of empty strings and than `array_filer()` delete it. But you can see again my last edit without `array_filter()` now.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tested this, but you might be able to use a regex to accomplish this.

```
s/\W/$1 /g
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe You can use preg_replace to achieve this. For example:

```
$string = "(good+bad)";
echo preg_replace('/\W+/', ' $0 ', $string);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is similar to  [PHP - iterate on string characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601032/php-iterate-on-string-characters)

Basically use [str_split](http://us.php.net/str_split) and/or [preg_Split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Taken from the preg_split page (And slightly modified:

```
<?php
$str = "(alpah+beta)*ga/6";
$keywords = preg_split("/[\/\(\)\*\&\^\%\$\#\@\!\_\{\}\:\"\+\\\]/", "$str");
print_r($keywords);
// now we replace the keywords with itself + a space on the left and right.
$count = count($keywords);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    if ( $keywords[$i] == '') {
        unset($keywords[$i]);
    }

}
var_dump($keywords);
foreach ($keywords as &$key) {
     $str = preg_replace("/$key/", " $key ", "$str");
}
echo "Finally: $str";
?>
```

This was just a quick mockup of something that will do the job. (Remove the dumps/prints for production code)